# Tkinter Button Command Not Running

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, command

I have a button I made with Tkinter and when pressed it executes a command. That command is not running, I press the button and nothing happens.

```
def wallet():
    global wal_gui
    lgn_h.destroy()
    wal_gui = Tk()
    wal_gui.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
    wal_gui.geometry("250x140")
    wal_gui.configure(background='black')
    if float(get_bal_by_user_logged_in()) == 0.0001: # *get_bal_by_user_logged_in() is a command that gets the current users "currency" balance*
        dis_bal = 0
    else:
        dis_bal = float(get_bal_by_user_logged_in())
    current_bal = Label(wal_gui, text=f"Currency: {dis_bal}", bg="#1a1a1a", fg="#3EA7A8", font=("Consolas", 10))
    current_bal.place(x=10, y=10)

    wal_gui.mainloop()

def login_handler():
    global lgn_h
    if db_login: # If the users currency wallet login returns true (Successful Login)
        lgn_h = Tk()
        lgn_h.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        lgn_h.geometry("250x170")
        lgn_h.configure(background='black')
        success_label = Label(lgn_h, text="Login Success!", bg="#1a1a1a", fg="#079133", font=("Consolas", 12))
        success_label.place(x=55, y=10)
        enter_wallet = Button(lgn_h, text="Enter Wallet", height=2, width=12, command=wallet)
        enter_wallet.place(x=60, y=80)
        enter_wallet.configure(bg='#1a1a1a',font='Consolas',fg='#808080')

        lgn_h.mainloop()
```

I tried looking for people with similar problems on here for the last 45 minutes or so, but couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Comment: When I run your code and click the button, the function is called. Though, you're calling `Tk()` more than once which will have behaviors you might not expect.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, I'll look more into the code.

Comment: @den0game try using `Toplevel` for new windows